# How do I build just the LatinIME package from AOSP?

Tags: android

I'm trying to test some changes that I made to the LatinIME package in AOSP. The problem is, that the documentation only shows how to build the entire thing.

What I really need to know is how to build a single package (in this case, LatinIME), from the command line

edit: What isn't made clear (at least to me), is that in the repo root directory, you can type make PACKAGE (e.g. `make LatinIME'), and it will build that. I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it does appear to build all the prerequisites of the required package as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the `mm` or `mmm` command. See [this documentation](http://elinux.org/Android_Build_System)

> Building only an individual program or module
>
> If you use build/envsetup.sh, you can use some of the defined functions to build only a part of the tree. Use the 'mm' or 'mmm' commands to do this.
>
> The 'mm' command makes stuff in the current directory (and sub-directories, I believe). With the 'mmm' command, you specify a directory or list of directories, and it builds those.
>
> To install your changes, do 'make snod' from the top of tree. 'make snod' builds a new system image from current binaries.